# My RecyclerView is not showing any data Android Studio(Kotlin, ViewBinding)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I am creating a weather app in which the recycler view is suppose to show today's forecast but is not showing anything. I am also not getting any kind of error in my code.

I have tried everything I could as I am a novice.
Below is the code for my Adapter class
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTxis.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA10S.png)
Below is the main activity function in which I am trying to fetch the data
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vAyx.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code, you have to fix your `viewBinding` implementation. I am assuming that:

- Data from api are correct
- `getItemsCount()` returns more than zero:

I will try to explain:

**Problem**

Problem is probably caused by `binding` property in `Forcastadapter`. Now you have one reference of binding which is being redeclared on every 'onCreateViewHolder' call. But in `onBindViewHolder` you are creating another instance of `ForcastViewBinding` which is getting updated, but it's not visible.

**Solution**

There is no reason to keep view binding inside adapter class. Just keep it inside `ViewHolder` and always use one binding for each viewHolder.

```kotlin
inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ForcastViewBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

Then update `onCreateViewHolder`:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
   val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
   val binding = ForcastViewBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
   return ViewHolder(binding)
}
```

And in `onBindViewHolder` replace:

```kotlin
val binding = ForcastViewBinding.bind(holder.itemView)
```

with

```kotlin
val binding = holder.binding
```

Comment: Still not working.....but thank you for the help

Comment: @harshShrimali please can you update your answer and provide code instead of screenshots so we can better figure out if there are any other possible bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't use the inner ViewHolder class at all, and just return the Viewholder from `onCreateViewHolder` like this `return ViewHolder(binding.root)` to give it a view, then it will render, and in `onBindViewHolder` you can access the view like this `holder.itemView.findViewById...`

Or more elegant to create your ViewHolder with a binding, and access it in `onBindViewHolder` with `val binding = holder.binding`. This will give you access to the views of the binding in `onBindViewHolder` by using this `val myView = binding.someView` and from there you can build your list item.

Comment: Still not working.....but thank you for the help